# Decorator Chaining of Repositories and Specialized Repositories with Dependancy Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, decorator-chaining

Right now I'm trying to figure out a way to do things smarter, and in the course of doing so all i've managed to do is use a full bottle of excedrin in a single day.

Assume i have an interface called IRepository like so.

```
 public interface IRepository<T>
 {
    T Get(int id);
    void Add(T value);
    void Update(T value);
    void Delete(T value);
    ...
 }
```

And assume i have an implementation like

```
public class NHibernateRepository<T>
{
    ...
}
```

Now, all is fine and good, i can do all my basic operations against the repository to support all CRUD functionality, but i may want specialized operations, so assume i have an interface like this:

```
public interface IUserRepository : IRepository<User>
{
     IList<User> GetUsersByRole(Role role);
}
```

And an implementation like such:

```
public class UserRepository : NHibernateRepository<User>, IUserRepository
{
    ....
}
```

Ok, so that is the basic setup, now there's one more thing that i want to do. I want to have logging and transaction and things like that all transparently. So what i would like to do is use a dependency injection framework like Castle Windsor or StructureMap so that when i ask for IRepository, i'll get it wrapped by a LoggingRepository and a TransactionRepository, both of which implement IRepository.

So, what i want to do is something like this:

```
IUserRepository repository = container.Resolve< IUserRepository>();
```

and have it return a user repository that's wrapped in the Logging and Transaction decorators, but i can't think of a way that this will ever work. The only way i can think of getting this to work is by implementing UserRepository like such:

```
public class UserRepository : DecoratorRepository<T>, IUserRepository
{
    protected IRepository<T> Repository { get; set; }

    public UserRepository(IRepository<T> innerRepository)
    {
        Repository = innerRepository;
    }
}
```

This would mean that we would use Dependancy Injection to create a decorated repository and pass that into the constructor of the UserRepository and then use that as the repository in which we run operations against.  This would work, but i still don't think it's ideal.

So, my question is, am I right in that this is the only way to do this, or am I not understanding this correctly or just missing something all together. Also, if you have run up against this problem before, how did you solve this problem?

Comment: Hi Darren. I'm very interested in how you solved this problem since I'm in exactly the same situation with both Custom Repositories that Closes a Open generic Repository<T> class with custom query methods and simple Open generic repositories that can easily be decorated. Please let me know…

Comment: @MagnusBackeus I ended up not doing decorated repositories as most of the things I thought I would be using them for ended up in other aspects of code (for example transactions went to `UnitOfWork`). I have the generic repository injected pretty much everywhere, including when I introduce specialized repositories like `IUserRepository`, it just gets `IRepository<User>` injected in. However, I never make classes that conflict with the generic repository (ie I wouldn't make `UserRepository : IRepository<User>`), I always introduce new interface.

Comment: Interesting approach… I've gone that path in my mind but always stop my thoughts with the problem "Where should I put Custom repository methods" like your  IList<User> GetUsersByRole(Role role) above. You express these new extended methods through other interfaces??

Comment: Yeah, I always introduce `IUserRepository` and just inject `IRepository<User>` into it.

Comment: I've also added different objects like Query objects before, so could be something else you add vs a method depending on what you are doing.

Comment: Ok.. like in your example. You inject IRepository<TEntity> into UserRepository so in a way you are decorating your generic repository with a custom repository. In that way you cannot use generic decorator but you seems to have skipped that part and moved transaction elsewhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to use [decorators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) that sounds about right. Each decorator would have a constructor with an argument of IRepository and call the logging or transaction code around calls to the inner repository that it is decorating.

As an alternative you might consider, but that I have very little experience with is Aspect Oriented Programming. In that scenario you apply attributes to your classes that indicate what logging or transaction methods you want to use. At some point those methods get weaved into your code, this can be done as either as an extra compile step, or in the case of the [SpringFramework.net](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop.html) at time of injection.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you have a  LoggingRepository abstract base class that would handle logging for your different Get, Add, Update, Delete, make them virtual and then inherit from them?

I'm not sure though what problem you are trying to solve though as I would think you may have tried this?  You could wrap in transactions as well, though most likely you'd want to do that in your NHibernateRepository.