# Decorating Repositories with AutoFac

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, decorator, autofac

Hi I have a maybe a common problem that I think not entirely can be solved by Autofac or any IoC container. It can be a design problem that I need some fresh input on.

I have the classic MVC web solution with EF 6. Its been implemented in a true DDD style with Anti-corruption layer, three bounded contexts, cross-cutting concerns movers out to infrastructure projects. It has been a real pleasure to see all pieces fall in to place in good way. We also added Commands to CUD operations into Domain.

Now here is the problem. Customer want a change log that tracks every entities property and when updates are done we need to save into change log values before and after update. We have implemented that successful in a `ILoggerService` that wraps a Microsoft test utility that we uses to detect changes. But I, my role is Software Architect, took the decision to Decorate our generic repositories with a `ChangeTrackerRepository` that have a dependency on `ILoggerService`. This works fine. The Decorator track methods `Add(…)` and `Modify(…)` in our `IRepository<TEntity>`.

The problem is that we have Repositories that have custom repositories that have custom queries like this:

```
public class CounterPartRepository : Repository<CounterPart>, ICounterPartRepository
{
    public CounterPartRepository(ManagementDbContext unitOfWork)
        : base(unitOfWork)
    {}

    public CounterPart GetAggregate(Guid id)
    {
        return GetSet().CompleteAggregate().SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
    }

    public void DeleteCounterPartAddress(CounterPartAddress address)
    {
       RemoveChild(address);
    }

    public void DeleteCounterPartContact(CounterPartContact contact)
    {
        RemoveChild(contact);
    }


}
```

We have simple repositories that just closes the generic repository and get proper EF Bounded context injected into it (Unit Of Work pattern):

```
public class AccrualPeriodTypeRepository : Repository<AccrualPeriodType>, IAccrualPeriodTypeRepository
    {
        public AccrualPeriodTypeRepository(ManagementDbContext unitOfWork)
            : base(unitOfWork)
        {
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when decorating AccrualPeriodTypeRepository with AutoFac through generic Decorator we can easily inject that repo into CommandHandler actor like this

```
public AddAccrualPeriodCommandHandler(IRepository<AccrualPeriod> accrualRepository)
```

This works fine.

But How do we also decorate CounterPartRepository???

I have gone through several solutions in my head and they all end up with a dead-end.

1) Manually decorate every custom repository generate to many custom decorators that it will be near unmaintainable.

2) Decorate the closed Repository Repository with extended custom queries. This smells bad. Should be part of that repository?

3) If we consider 2… maybe Skip our Services and only rely on IRepository for operating on our Aggregate Roots and IQueryHandler (see article https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92)

I need some fresh input to a common problem I think, when it comes to decorating your repositories when you have custom closed repositories and simple repositories also closed but both inherit from same Repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you consider decorating command handlers instead of decorating repositories?
Repos are too low level, and it is not their responsibility to know what should be logged and how.

What about the following:

1) You have your command handlers in a way:

```
public class DeleteCounterPartAddressHandler  : IHandle<DeleteCounterPartAddressCommand> 
{
    //this might be set by a DI container, or passed to a constructor
    public ICounterPartRepository Repository { get; set; }    

    public void Handle(DeleteCounterPartAddressCommand command)
    {
         var counterpart = repository.GetPropertyById(command.CounterPartId);

         // in DDD you always want to read and aggregate 
         // and save an aggregate as a whole
         property.DeleteAdress(command.AddressId);

         repository.Save(counterpart)
    }
}
```

2) Now you can simply use Chain Of Responsibility pattern to "decorate" your handlers with logging, transactions, whatever:

```
public class LoggingHandler<T> : IHandler<T>  {
    private readonly IHandler<T> _innerHandler;

    public LoggingHandler(IHandler<T> innerHandler)  {
            _innerHandler = innerHandler;
    }

    public void Handle(T command) 
    {
        //Obviously you do it properly, but you get the idea
        _log.Info("Before");
        _innerHandler.Handle(command);
        _log.Info("After");
    }
}
```

Now you have just one piece of code responsible for logging and you can *compose* it with any command handler, so if you ever want to log a particular command then you just "wrap" it with the logging handler, and it is still your `IHandle<T>` so the rest of the system is not impacted.
And you can do it with other concerns too (threading, queueing, transactions, multiplexing, routing, etc.) without messing around and plumbing this stuff here and there.
Concerns are very well separated this way.

It is also much better (to me) because you log on a real operation (business) level, rather than on low-level repository.

Hope it helps.

**P.S.** In DDD you really want your repositories to only expose aggregate-level methods because Aggregates suppose to take care of their invariants (and nothing else, no services, no repositories), and because Aggregate represents transaction boundary.

Really, it is up to the Repository how to get the Aggregate from persisted storage and how to persist it back, outside it should look like you ask someone for an object and it gives you an object you can call behaviors on.

So normally you would only get an aggregate from the repository, call its behavior(s) and then save it back. Which really means that your repositories would mostly have GetById and Save methods, not some internals like "UpdateThatPartOfAnAggregate".

Comment: We do have Logging on Commandlevel. All our commands are serialized into Json and logged. Problem is that this Customer has specific business needs to Log changes. For example CounterPartAdressChanged: Street Before --> After, Zipcode Before --> After. But not Town because it hasn't been changed.

Comment: I totally agree with you about Aggregate boundaries and how CRUD should be done. Some of our CodeFirst mapping relations caused EF not to delete child entity in a Parent-child relation (within aggregate). So RemoveChild is a workaround. But we do have other custom (mostly read) methods like GetCounterPartByContractId(…) And method like that must exist due to the fact you cannot fetch all you info by unique Ids...

Comment: What's your experience with Repository methods that have a tendency towards query but within aggregate boundaries?

Comment: Another way to do it to represent changes not as a state, but as a stream of events (EventSourcing). Then your event log is an ultimate source of truth and a perfect 100% correct audit.

Comment: I don't completely understand your question about repositories and queries within aggregate. In my view aggregates don't have references to repositories at all. Domain don't depend on infrastructure. Id my aggregate needs something in order to perform its behavior it declares a dependency, usually in its behavior method. But it never accesses repositories. It is the other way around: repositories build aggregates.

Comment: I do understand DDD fundamentals and been doing DDD for sometime now and one key aspect is having your domain free of dependencies, like repositories. So our scenario is that we inject our repos in our command handlers in Application service layer. But Since I look at Changelog as a crosscutting concerns that I would like to move out to a infrastructure layer, it would be suitable if this could be handled by a RepositoryDecorator. Since we have info about entity before change and after change.

Comment: … and must say I'äm really appreciate your new input about this problem. But I'm totally into your ideas about logging at command level, which we are doing today. But we need a lower level logging at Entity level.

Comment: I just found this article… here at SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439729/decorator-chaining-of-repositories-and-specialized-repositories-with-dependancy?rq=1 It is basically the same problem. But no working solution though...